# angular 2 rc7 - testing service - Error: No provider for String

Tags: unit-testing, angular, dependency-injection, angular2-services

I've getting an error in angular 2 testing using the webpack quickstart project.

> Error: No provider for String! in config/karma-test-shim.js

I've never seen this error where the provider for String is missing. I figured out its related the private url:string in the services constructor but how do I resolve it?

Here's my testfile

```
describe('http.ts',()=>{
    beforeEach(()=>{
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers:[
                SbHttp,
                MockBackend,
                BaseRequestOptions,
                { provide: Http, useFactory: (backend: MockBackend, defaultOptions: BaseRequestOptions) => {
                    return new Http(backend, defaultOptions);
                }, deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]}
            ],
            imports: [
                HttpModule
            ]
        })
    });

    afterEach(()=>{
        TestBed.resetTestingModule()

    });

    it('get() should work', inject([SbHttp],(sbHttp:SbHttp)=>{
        expect(true).toBeTruthy()

    }))
})
```

and here's the SbHttp service

```
@Injectable()
export class SbHttp{

    private baseUrl:string;

    constructor( private url:string, private headers:Headers, private http:Http
    ){
        this.baseUrl = utils.stripTrailingSlash(url)
    }
}
```

If I change to private url:any I'm getting this error

> Can't resolve all parameters for SbHttp: (?, Headers, Http).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make it injectable by [creating a token](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#dependency-injection-tokens), using `@Inject()` to inject with the token, and then add it as a provider in the `providers` list .

```
import { OpaqueToken, Injct } from '@angular/core';

const APP_URL = new OpaqueToken('app.url');

class SbHttp {
  constructor(@Inject(APP_URL) url: string, ...) {}
}

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  providers: [
    { provide: APP_URL, useValue: 'http://localhost' }
  ]
});
```

You'll also need to configure the `providers` in the real app also. As for the `Headers`, I'm not sure, but I think you might get the error also once you fix this one. I'm not sure where you expect to be getting that from.

I highly suggest you take a look at the [dependency injection chapter](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html) from the Angular documentation if you are new to DI with Angular.

Comment: thanks for the answer! I will read through the DI more thoroughly this time :)